# What does <<<x,y>>> mean between the function name and its arguments?

Tags: c++, syntax, cuda, caffe

I am learning caffe(bvlc).

When I analyzed code, I found strange code I didn't know.

like this :

```
im2col_gpu_kernel<Dtype><<<CAFFE_GET_BLOCKS(num_kernels),
                         CAFFE_CUDA_NUM_THREADS>>>(
  num_kernels, data_im, height, width, kernel_h, kernel_w, pad_h,
  pad_w, stride_h, stride_w, dilation_h, dilation_w, height_col,
  width_col, data_col);
```

When I commentted to im2col_gpu_kernel func, I found tons of calling about that func.

So I guessed "<<< >>>" this code conducting loop(like for, while) calling about func.

Is it? or Is there another role?
and Is this code c++ std library?

Comment: Exactly where did you find that? AFAIK that's not valid C++. Could it be that it's some kind of (non-standard) preprocessing involved?

Comment: It is CUDA. https://www.google.com.tr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=cuda+triple+angle+brackets&*

Comment: Thank you! @HumamHelfawi

Answer (score 5):

This triple angled-bracket notation is part of CUDA runtime syntaxic sugar. It is a placehoder to configure a device call execution - see [CUDA programming model](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#programming-model) for details.